# Change ICEPDF Look And Feel in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, frameworks, icepdf

I am using IcePDF as PDF viewer, with the `PropertiesManager` I can enable/disable functionalities like for example :

```
    SwingController controller = new SwingController();

    PropertiesManager properties = new PropertiesManager(System.getProperties(),
            ResourceBundle.getBundle(PropertiesManager.DEFAULT_MESSAGE_BUNDLE));

    properties.setBoolean(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_UTILITY_PRINT, false);
    properties.setBoolean(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_TOOLBAR_ANNOTATION, false);
    properties.setBoolean(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_UTILITYPANE_ANNOTATION, false);
    properties.setBoolean(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_TOOLBAR_ROTATE, false);
    properties.setBoolean(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_UTILITY_SAVE, false);
    properties.setBoolean(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_TOOLBAR_FIT, false);

    SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller, properties);
```

But I want to change the Windows Look And Feel, a simple `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` doesn't work. Can someone have the solution ?

Comment: What Look and Feel do you want to set ? It seems you are setting what is already set

Comment: The windows one, because by default it's "metal" I think, it's not very beautiful...

Comment: Anyone ? I can't find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally just added to the beginning of my code that :

```
try {
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
        | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
  System.err.println("[ err. ] " + e);
}
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The class org.icepdf.ri.viewer.Launcher sets up the look and feel of the Viewer RI which is found in the viewer jar. This is an older class but it still uses the PropertiesManager if you want to override it.  You can do with with:

```
preferences.put("application.lookandfeel", "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
```

This is for ICEpdf 6.3.x but you can uses a similar pattern as your original post if you are on an earlier version.   The value can be any valid Look and feel for Swing.

Comment: Hello, I did that with `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel` to set the Windows LookandFeel, but nothing happen :/